# React hooks - useEffect updating state but the updated state is not re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, use-effect

**Background of the problem**

I have a problem with my React Hook.

Basically, I want to re-render my `<li>` components (named `elementsToDisplay` in the code below) when the user changes the order to display them or when the user enters a search string in a text input element to filter them.

```
//...import statements here...

function myHook(props) {
    const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('') // Initially empty searchstirng
    const [order, setOrder] = useState('order1') // Ordering is initially order1
    const [myObjects, setObjects] = useState(props.myObjects) // The objects needed to create the elements to display
    const [elementsToDisplay, setElementsToDisplay] = useState([]) // The <li> elements to display (based on myObjects)
    
     /* 
        IF THE SEARCHSTING OR THE ORDER GET CHANGED BY THE USER, CHANGE MY OBJECTS
    */
   useEffect(() => {
       var myObjectsCopy = [... props.myObjects]
       myObjectsCopy.sort((a,b) => {
           // Ordina in base a cosa l' utente ha selezionato dal sortByButton.
           if (order == 'order1'){
               // return some ordering
            }
            else if (order == 'order2'){
                // return some ordering
            }
            else if (order == 'order3'){
                // return some ordering
            }
            else{
                // return some ordering
            }
        })
        var newObjects = myObjectsCopy.filter(item => {
             // filter based on searchsting
             return item.productCode.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) >= 0
         })
       setObjects(newObjects)
       console.log(myObjects[0]) // NOTE here myObjects get updated as expected everytime
   }, [order, searchString])


   /*
      When myObjects change, so the <li> elements to display should (end they do!).
   */
    useEffect(()=>{
        var elements = get_elements_to_display()
        setElementsToDisplay(elements)
        console.log(elementsToDisplay[0]) // NOTE, elementsToDisplay change as expected!!!!!!
    },[myObjects])



    /*
       Function that creates the <li> elements to display based on myObjects. NOTE works fine
    */
     function get_elements_to_display(){
        return myObjects.map((item, index) => {
            var competitors = item.competitors
            return(
                <li key={index}>
                    <span className='produt-separator'/>
                    <ProductTable item={item} index={index} />
                </li>
            )
        })
    }

    

    /*
       Change the ordering to display the elements. NOTE Work as expected!!!
    */
    function handleChangeOrder(e, value) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(value) // NOTE the right ordering gets passed
        setOrder(value)
        console.log(order) // NOTE order gets updated as expected
    }


   
    /*
       Render the component
    */
     return (
            <div>
                <h1 className='page-title'>My Title</h1>
                <input className="search-input" type='text' 
                    onChange={e => setSearchString(e.target.value)} 
                    placeholder='Cerca il toner o cartuccia per nome...'></input>
                <span width="8px"/>
                <SortByButton handleClick={handleChangeOrder}/>
                <AddProductPopUp/>
                <ul>
                    {elementsToDisplay}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )

}
```

**Problem**

The problem is that all my state variables get changed as expected, but the rendered `<li>` components stay the same. This is weird as they are stored in the state `elementsToDisplay` and I can see that it gets updated whenever I select a new ordering or try to filter my elements inputting a search string.

Can you see if I am doing something wrong from the sample code I posted?

Comment: Have you tried changing the key of the list `<li key={index}>` to some unique identifier other than `index`? Also, can we get a CodeSandBox to replicate the issue that you're facing?

Comment: @AreebKhan You are my savior. Changing ```key=``` prop to something unique did the trick. However I don't get what's the logic behind it. Would you mind posting an answer with some explanation so I can set it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes of course. React uses keys to detect what items in a list have changed. Since you're using index as a key in non-static instances, and later sort the array out from which you're rendering, the order of the indices remain the same.  (1/2)

Comment: In other words, before sorting a dynamic array `[y,x,z]` and using their index as key, React basically associates `y` with 0, `x` with 1 and `z` with 2. Post sort the array becomes `[x,y,z]` and the order of the elements have changed, but the item having index 0 is still first! Now because React uses keys to detect changes, and we've kept indices as keys (the order of which do not change pre and post sort), React doesn't render the change.

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)
(2/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the comments)

Changing the key of the list `<li key={index}>` to some unique identifier other than `index` will fix it.

React uses keys to detect what items in a list have changed. Since you're using index as a key in non-static instances, and later sort the array out from which you're rendering, the order of the indices remain the same.